# How to add a self signed certificate to the trusted browser certificates?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, certificate, openssl, chromium

My system is `Linux Mint 19.1`, `Chromium` browser.

Having hard time with that red information bar at browser address. I have a web server that has my certificate and a key. The certificate pair generated like so:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -sha256 -days 3650 -nodes -keyout my_file.key -out my_file.crt \
      -subj /CN=AMAZON_ADDRESS.compute.amazonaws.com\
      -addext subjectAltName=DNS:AMAZON_ADDRESS.amazonaws.com,IP:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

The `Chromium` browser connects to my `https` address but still rejects the certificate with:

```
This server could not prove that it is 18.220.1.136; 
its security certificate is not trusted by your computer's operating system.
```

I have tried numerous suggestions found on the internet and SO sites.

1) Add the certificate to NSS DB, as found here: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/docs/linux_cert_management.md

```
certutil -d sql:/home/MYLAP/.pki/nssdb/ -A -t "P,," -n xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -i my_file.crt
```

2) Import the certificate with `Chromium` menu.

3) Add the certificate to my OS trusted certificates by putting it in `/usr/share/ca-certificates` directory and running `update-ca-certificates`

The above actions still get me to `Chromium` browser warning.
My question is, how to properly generate certificate pair and add it to the browser trust chain?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/1296596/how-can-i-get-chrome-accepting-self-signed-certificates?  Did you restart Chromium?

Comment: Somehow related, yes. But as I have mentioned is the question, I did all the steps and it not helped. Also the question you mentioned dates to 2018. Please read the question carefully before posting a duplicate. And yes I did restart `Chromium` and the `OS`.

Comment: Did you set *Trust this certificate for identifying websites* in the certificate's settings?

Comment: @mat please tell me how to add this option. Is this OpenSSL setting for certificate generation?

Comment: No, its a browser setting. For every certificate in your browser's trust store you set *trust settings* which specify what the certificacte should be used for.

Comment: @mat Can you point me how to do it? My attempts did not work.

Comment: @mat I used browser import certificate feature. The certificate was added but the warning still shows up.

Comment: In Chromium: Open *Settings* -> *Manage Certificates*. Search for the certificate authority that makes problems and click *Edit*. In that window you can set the *Trust settings* where you activate the checkbox for *identifying webseites*

Comment: @mat I've tried the Chtomium settings way earlier. Still does not work. I wrote that in my answer.